# Displaying datetime on a chart x axis and subsequently on a tooltip showing x and y axis value

Tags: c#, sql, charts

```
namespace TRSQL
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
private ImageList imagelst;
public SqlDataReader dr1;
public Form1()
{
    imagelst = new ImageList();
    InitializeComponent();
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
    timer.Interval = 1000;
}

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    timer.Enabled = false;
    button1.PerformClick();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.Clear();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server=HIST;database=PLC_DB;uid=sa;password=NCADMIN@123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [PLC_DB].[dbo].[EVEREST] WHERE DATESTR   BETWEEN '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd ") + "' AND '" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "'", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr1.Read())
    {
        chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.Clear();
        chart1.Series["Series1"].Color = Color.Red;
        chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(dr1["DATESTR"].ToString(), dr1["Value"].ToString());
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Enabled = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.AxisEnabled.True;
        chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
        //chart1.Update();
        ////chart1.Series.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 1;
        chart1.Series["Series1"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 250;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 200;


    }
    con.Close();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


}



private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.Clear();
    chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.Clear();
    string selected = comboBox1.Text;
   // label1.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server=HIST;database=PLC_DB;uid=sa;password=NCADMIN@123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  top (10) * FROM [PLC_DB].[dbo].[EVEREST] WHERE [DATESTR] > DATEADD(HOUR, - " + selected + ", GETDATE())", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr1.Read())
    {

        chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(dr1["Tag1"].ToString(), dr1["TagValue1"].ToString());
        chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY(dr1["Tag2"].ToString(), dr1["TagValue2"].ToString());
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Enabled = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.AxisEnabled.True;
        chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
        chart1.Series[1].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
        chart1.Series["Series1"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        chart1.Series["Series2"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        //chart1.Series["Series2"].Label



    }
    con.Close();

}

private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void hScrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{

}

private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dateTimePicker1 = new DateTimePicker();
    dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
    dateTimePicker1.ShowUpDown = true;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.Clear();
    string selected = comboBox1.Text;
    // label1.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server=HIST;database=PLC_DB;uid=sa;password=NCADMIN@123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  *  FROM [PLC_DB].[dbo].[TEMP] WHERE [DATESTR] > DATEADD(HOUR, - " + selected + ", GETDATE())", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr1.Read())
    {
        chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(dr1["Tag"].ToString(), dr1["TagValue"].ToString());
        chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY(dr1["Tag"].ToString(), dr1["TagValue"].ToString());
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Enabled = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.AxisEnabled.True;
        chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
        chart1.Series[1].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
        chart1.Series["Series1"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 250;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 200;


    }
    con.Close();

}
}
 }
```

I am working on c# windows form where i have to show a trend for sql server data coming in on different date and time. There are two parameters one is DATESTR which is on X-axis and second is Values which is on Y-axis . Tooltip is only showing Y-axis values but unable to show X-axis Values. In chart, it is showing 0 as the value of x axis.

Comment: Welcome to `StackOverflow[SO]`, [please be a bit more specific when asking question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): What have you tried so far with code example? / What do you expect? / What error do you get? For more quality in your question, please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) & [Why is your question not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Why do you clear all points in the loop? What does the result look like? - Also: Do include System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting in the using clausesto avoid this terrible redundancy!!!